# Lidar point cloud and ambient occlusion shading

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, point-clouds, ambient-occlusion

I'm trying to replicated the way sketchfab visualizes lidars. The color of each point seem to be determined by some kind of ambient occlusion technique.

What I tried:

1. Tried plugging an ambient occlusion shader in the emission, but it gave me little rounded spheres while as you can see on the sketchfab ref, each point is represented as a flat shaded disc/sphere
2. Tried using a the geometry proximity node in geometry nodes, but I realized recreating an ambient occlusion effect isn't that straightforward.
3. In theory I should convert the lidar point cloud into a polygonal mesh, then bake the ambient occlusion values to the vertexes, then turn the whole thing back into a point cloud where each point has a color value I have access to. I couldn't find a way in blender to convert a point cloud into a mesh so far.

Let me know if anyone has any ideas, thanks!

[sketchfab link](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/auckland-lidar-ao-0312d2617da64de3a518aa561277e144)

[image]